# Meaning of notation with two letters inside of parentheses [binomial coefficient]

Tags: notation, math-history

What does the notation in the red box mean?

$$\Huge e^{\displaystyle \large \sum_{k=0}^n \bbox[2px,border:2px solid red]{\color{black}
{ {n \choose k}}}~\omega^k}$$

Comment: See [Binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Comment: @Giteshwar Mali I edited your post to use mathjax formatting rather than the image, I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$n\choose{k}$ is a 'binomial coefficient'.  Sometimes read '$n$ choose $k$.  It represents the number of ways of choosing $k$ items from $n$ distinct items where the order of choice is unimportant.

The value is ${{n}\choose {k}}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

$n$ and $k$ are nonnegative integers with $k\le n$.

Answer (score 1):

Binomial coefficients. Relevant here is that:

$\begin{align}
  \sum_{0 \le k \le n} \binom{n}{k} a^k b^{n - k}
    = (a + b)^n
\end{align}$

Comment: And so the exponent in the question is $(1+\omega)^{n}.$

Answer (score 0):

The image is of $(^n_k)$ and it means the number of $\mathbf{combinations}$, i.e. it denotes the number of ways in which $k$ things can be chosen from $n$ things.